# What is an Unstable Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles. Wanted to try making one of these for myself.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it an Unstable Word™.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Unstable Words™ | Not Unstable Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| CHLORINE | BROMINE |
| HORSES | CHICKENS |
| INITIATE | COMMENCE |
| MASSIVE | MIGHTY |
| MOUNTAIN | VALLEY |
| POISON | VENOM |
| PROMPT | SWIFT |
| RESOLUTE | DECISIVE |
| RICKETY | DERELICT |
| SNOOKER | SOCCER |
| UMBRELLA | PARASOL |
| UNSTABLE | WOBBLY |
| VISION | REVERIE |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Unstable Words™,Not Unstable Words™
CHLORINE,BROMINE
HORSES,CHICKENS
INITIATE,COMMENCE
MASSIVE,MIGHTY
MOUNTAIN,VALLEY
POISON,VENOM
PROMPT,SWIFT
RESOLUTE,DECISIVE
RICKETY,DERELICT
SNOOKER,SOCCER
UMBRELLA,PARASOL
UNSTABLE,WOBBLY
VISION,REVERIE
```

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is an Unstable Word™ without relying on the other words.
These are not the only examples of Unstable Words™; many more exist.

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The rule:

> The sum of all the letters (A = 1; Z = 26) should be the atomic number of a radioactive element in order for it to be an Unstable word.

Example:

> Take `HORSES`. When you sum up all the letters using the rule stated above, you get `8+15+18+19+5+19` = `84`. Element 84 is [Polonium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polonium), which is a radioactive element. Hence `HORSES` is an Unstable word. [Here](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@19cmqtgq2DAxZWWX6SQnJFYlJhcklqkkJkHRAWlJRqaVlwKCiBF2rYK@UUpGnAlmrpmJlxcBUWZeSUaQHnN//@dPXz8gzz9XAE) is a Python script that I came up with to calculate the sum of all the letters.

Counter-example:

> The sum for `BROMINE` is [`76`](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@19cmqtgq2DAxZWWX6SQnJFYlJhcklqkkJkHRAWlJRqaVlwKCiBF2rYK@UUpGnAlmrpmJlxcBUWZeSUaQHnN//@dgvx9Pf1cAQ). This corresponds to Element 76: [Osmium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmium), which is a stable element. Hence `BROMINE` is not an Unstable word.

Comment: Yep. Nice and simple. Well done!

Comment: "simple", yeah, that's just what I was thinking...